# Tic Tac Toe in Python practice 2

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

The previous code on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245628/tic-tac-toe-in-python-practice/245632#245632)

I'm quite novice here so apologies for any silly mistake in advance

I've been writing a simple tic tac toe game which is a part of my course in udemy

Since this is my first project, I want to do my best in order to learn new things besides learning how to code better. Generally, I want to optimize my code as much as possible.

Can anyone help me with this?

```py
# Tic Tac Toe
# 17 July 2020

import os

test_board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
player_input_num = 0    # numbers of inputs entered by player
player_num = 0
won = False
marker = 'X'


def clear_screen():
    os.system("clear")


def display_board(board_cords):
    '''
    display the board
    board_cords = list(left to right from top to bottom)
    '''
    line = '-'*40
    for counter in range(0, len(board_cords), 3):
        print("\t|\t\t|")
        print(
            f"{board_cords[counter]}\t|\t{board_cords[counter+1]}\t|\t{board_cords[counter+2]}")
        print(line)
        counter += 3    # go to next row


def check_player_input(number):
    if number < 10 and number >= 0:  # checking the range
        return True
    else:
        print('Sorry the input is not in range [0-9] .')
        return False


def player_input(player_in):
    global player_input_num  # access to player_input_num
    if player_input_num >= 2:
        # check if the position is free to use
        if check_capacity(test_board, player_in):
            result = place_marker(test_board, 'X', player_in)
            clear_screen()
            display_board(result)

            if check_win(test_board, marker):
                print("You Won!")
                global won
                won = True
        else:
            print("The current position is occupied.")
    else:
        if check_capacity(test_board, player_in):
            result = place_marker(test_board, 'X', player_in)
            clear_screen()
            display_board(result)
            player_input_num += 1
        else:
            print("The current position is occupied.")


def check_capacity(board, position):
    '''
    Check if the current position is free to use.
    '''
    return board[position] == ' '


def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    '''
    Replace the position with a marker
    '''
    board[position] = marker
    return board


def check_win(board, marker):
    '''
    Check if the current game is finished
    '''
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == marker:
        return True
    if board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == marker:
        return True
    if board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == marker:
        return True
    if board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == marker:
        return True
    if board[6] == board[7] == board[8] == marker:
        return True
    if board[2] == board[4] == board[6] == marker:
        return True
    return False


def wanna_play():
    answer = input("Wanna play again? (Y or N)")
    return answer


# Main
display_board(test_board)
while True:
    while won == False:
        try:  # checking if input is int
            player_num = int(input("Enter a position: "))
        except:
            print("Input is not a number")
            continue

        if check_player_input(player_num):
            player_input(player_num)

    if wanna_play() in ['y', 'Y', 'n', 'N']:
        print("something")
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        # print("Thanks for playing :)")
```

Note that code is working, I just want to know other ways of doing it and optimize it overalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using indices from 0 to 9, change the way you store your board to be a 3x3 list.

```py
board = list([[0] * 3] * 3)
"""
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
"""
```

This will allow you to come back to it and add a GUI.
It also becomes easier for anyone reading the code to understand what's happening visually.

Next is your printout of the board. Join will be your friend here.

```py
for row in board:
  printout = "\t|\t".join(str(element) for element in row)
  print(printout) # this can be reduced to a single line if you want.
```

#### ranges

`range()` accepts 3 variables. START, STOP and INCREMENT AMOUNT

```py
for i in range(0, 9, 3):
```

You can also reverse with negative values

```py
for i in range(9, 0, -1):
```

or

```py
for row in board[::-1]:
```

#### if statements

In math class you know how you were able to write a < x > b? You can do that in python without requiring `and`.

```py
if 0 <= number > 10:
```

Then there is checking the board state if someone has won.
Your current approach requires a lot of coding and can't be expanded on quickly

There are a few different approaches you can do with this. All will "work."

First the rows

```py
for row in board:
  if len(set(row)) == 1:
    return True
```

```py
for row in board:
  if all(element == row[0] for element in rows):
    return True
```

Diagonals next (I would use a tempory dummy variable for `len(board)` to increase readability. -> `_ = len(board)`

```py
if len(set(board[i][i] for i in range(len(board)) == 1:
  return True
if len(set(board[i][len(board)-i-1] for i in range(len(board)) == 1:
  return True
```

The columns can be a trickier but transposing would probably be the most pythonic way to approach it.

```py
board_T = [list(column) for column in zip(board)]
```

This will allow you to call the rows again and check to see if someone won.

It should be noted that the return values for the winner state could return the **PLAYER** of rather than `True` or `False`. Python sees 0, None, Empty iterables, and False as False in an if statement.

I also noticed you didn't follow a lot of the advice given to you in the original post. You are still lacking an `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement

```py
def playTicTacToe():
   display_board(test_board)
   ...

...
if __name__ == "__main__":
  playTicTacToe()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing help. But now I faced a problem. 
When I changed my code and do everything before **range** in your answer, the output is :
`[0, 0, 0]       |       [0, 0, 0]       |       [0, 0, 0]
Enter a position: `

Comment: And Yes. I searched for ___name___ thing but i just couldn't find how to use it in my code.

Comment: @Darklight I added a bit to the end to help with the name == main bit. Also, I had a typo at `board =` it should be `board = list([[0] * 3] * 3])`, sorry about that

Comment: @david_fisher Thanks for your help. I changed the `test_board` variable to `test_board = list([[' '] * 3] * 3)` but now the function `check_capacity()` always returns false

Comment: You need to convert your position to `y, x = position // 3, position % 3` and then run the check `return board[y][x] == ' '` Btw, you'll also need to have these values for when you place your 'X' and 'O'

Comment: @david_fisher So i guess it would make the code more unreadable, wouldn't it? I think my code was better for optimization. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: If you were looking for optimization, you wouldn't be writing it in python. You use python for maintainability, readability, and the ease in writing and deploying. If you wanted to optimize it completely, you'd build it in C and make every board state static. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110768/discussion-between-darklight-and-david-fisher).